# vertical-align does not work

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="title_right mid_center top_menu">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/ComoFunciona">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Tarifas">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Contacto">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Security/Account">
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.page-title .title_right {
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.mid_center {
    width: 370px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

div.top_menu {
    height: 167px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How can I center those buttons vertically? I don't want to patch it using padding.

Comment: Add the style property `vertical-align: middle` to each `.btn`. `vertical-align` specifies the alignment for the elements you've applied the property to as opposed to the children of that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display: table-cell` with your `vertical-align: middle` should do it.

```css
.page-title .title_right {
  width: 55%;
}

.mid_center {
    width: 370px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

div.top_menu {
    height: 167px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_right mid_center top_menu">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/ComoFunciona">1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Tarifas">2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Contacto">3</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Security/Account">4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I have changed only `div.top_menu` styles:

```css
.page-title .title_right {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.mid_center {
    width: 370px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: violet;
}

div.top_menu {
    height: 167px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_right mid_center top_menu">
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/ComoFunciona">1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Tarifas">2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Home/Contacto">3</a>
  <a class="btn btn-app" href="/Security/Account">4</a>
</div>
```

Need to say, that it's a crossbrowser solution, but some old browser doesn't support flexbox.

Comment: It did not work for me.... what may be affecting?

Comment: In this code snippet "1", "2", "3" and "4" are not in the middle of screen?

Comment: When i said "screen", i meant the `div` element

Comment: your sample works, but my code does not.